# Css fixed width + 100% padding. is it possible with one container?

Tags: css

I need to make ui controls panel, that has 100% width and gradient background. UI elements on this control panel should have width 1000px and should be centered.

For a moment i have two elements:
panel (width 100%, gradient background), global wrapper
panel-wrapper (width 1000px, transparent background), is placed inside "panel" element, contains UI elements.

It works brilliant in all browsers i need, but i really don't like to use two HTML elements, when logically it should be just one. Perhaps it is possible to have one element "panel" with fixed width (1000px) and auto-padding, that will cover all free space to the left and to the right? (i've made an image to show it if my explanation is crazy :))

[image]

It is possible?

Comment: Your image still seems to imply you need two containers.

Comment: On image there is only one container, green color here is just to display fixed width for elements. Or you mean that i have anyway to use two containers? :'(

Comment: This may be of interest to you: [the body *is* a wrapper](http://camendesign.com/code/developpeurs_sans_frontieres)

Comment: Ah, I see what you are asking. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Does the body count as a container?  Set the dark gray background on the body. Then create your green container and set the fixed width and use `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: If i will use body as wrapper it will be still two wrappers.
I tried to make one element with width:100px and padding:100% but result is not that i supposed :(

Comment: ultimately, I think `padding: auto` would be the solution if it worked like `margin: auto`, alas that's not an implemented concept in CSS (AFAIK).

Comment: @DA Really i had same idea, i've tried it, but padding:auto displays no padding at all :((

Comment: Right, it's not a supported thing. Seems like it should be. But I guess the W3C disagrees. ;)

Comment: Use CSS functions, e.g., `padding-left: max(calc(100vw - 1000px), 0px)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use the `calc()` function, though it isn't highly browser compliant.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/imerit/1/edit) is a quick example and more information on compatibility and usage can be found [here](http://webdesignernotebook.com/css/the-wonderful-calc-function/).

*I made the example in Firefox, didn't test it elsewhere.

Just for a quick code example, the following shows one solution:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: calc(50% - 50px);
  padding-right: calc(50% - 50px);

}
```

Comment: along these lines, JS could easily handle this. That said, from an optimization POV, I think the extra wrapper is likely a better option.

Comment: @DA, Fully agree with you. Two wrappers with css is much better with one + javascript.

Comment: @mookamafoob I tried to use "padding-left: calc(100% - 1000px)" to test, but it seems not to work even in Firefox.. :(

Comment: @true Just updated the answer and sample, but you may need -moz-calc() for Firefox

Comment: @mookamafoob i had to update my FF version (i had 14.x, that has bad calc support).

Thank very much for your answer. though it is not crossbrowser solution, it works perfectly.

Comment: @true Glad to point out a solution (albeit imperfect). It does work on IE9 and up as well as webkit I believe, so I guess it depends who you need to cater to. :)

Comment: Just checked - it does not work on ios safari, winos chrome (just tested), so i can't use this solution (we need chrome support at least). But it is a correct answer, it works fine in FF. I hope in nearest future i will be able to use it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @mookamafoob i've just changed little bit css code to calculate  paddings correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is you can't really combine percentages and fixed widths with padding in the traditional sense, since the padding is added to the total width.

If the total width is 100%, and you want the content in the center to be 500px, you can't calculate the padding.

With CC3, though, you can use the `box-sizing` to change 'where' the padding is placed in the box model.

http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/

Alas, I still don't think that will give you want you want simply due to there still being an unknown variable in play (the width of the container that the 100% width object is in).

In the end, we can sometimes over think these solutions in the name of over-optimization. IN this case, an extra div seems perfectly acceptable and, likely, the proper solution.

Comment: Thanks very much, did not know about this...
So, this way, we can setup width to element including it's borders, paddings, everything.. but anyway we will need to calculate paddings to the left or right side to have 1000px for content in the middle of our HTML element, right?

Comment: You summed up the problem with with the 'we need to calculate' bit. That's the whole catch. The CSS, alone, can't calculate that variable given the variances of the '100%' outer width.

Answer (score -1):

Why `padding` ?

You could set left and right margins to `auto` and that would make the div centered..

So just set

```
.panel{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Right, but there will be no background with 100% width.
For a moment i have same solution for inner wrapper (that is centered and has transparent background), when outer wrapper has 100% width and gradient background.

But i wanted to make one element if it is possible

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But, this way i would have to still use my solution with two wrappers, but main wrapper will be body. I wanted to understand, if it posible to play around with paddings, to have only one wrapper..

Comment: i really can't see the point of this. as any element will be inside another... even `body` is inside `html` and you could style that (*the body*) to be centered inside `html`.. So i really can't see where you could use this ability even if it existed.. Could you post a case where that would be helpful ?

Comment: Just to have less HTML elements on the page. I have lots of widgets that have same issue with wrappers. Less HTML, less javascript (because wrappers are controlled by js) gives better environment to workaround...